# Monitor bandwidth consumption for all connected PC over wifi

Tags: wifi, bandwidth, bandwidth-measuring

We have two internet connection connected to individual wifi router (beetel) in our office, lately i am experiencing very slow internet connection or frequent connection drops, when complained to ISP, they say everything is good from their end, and  problem could only come from our side, I am not convinced about this somehow.

I see various possibility that may be causing this slow connection issue:
1. Network congestion
2. Someone connected to internet is consuming data by downloading
3. Router
4. ISP

I want to find out root of this issue, to start with I want to check bandwidth consumption of each connected computers, for this i am wondering, is there a tool (preferably for Mac, or Ubuntu/Windows) that will report me instantly the current bandwidth consumption of each connected computers? I want to see who is consuming how much of bandwidth.

I will also be glad to hear any ideas that will help me track root of this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a transparent proxy and/or a firewall behind your router. With this you can monitor and control your environment. There are hundreds of commercial and open source solutions for this.

Comment: Can you point me to the device you are referring to?

Comment: Well, there is no device I am referring to. Product placement is not allowed here...As a starting point I would take a look and Squid and pfSense and see if this fits your needs.